# Regular expression to get after character a specific pattern

Tags: regex, python-3.x

**Input String :**

```
-line[8qWWQ5-swd-WER-DWDS]]<-SUCCESS#[14][MY_SAMPLE_TEST]
-line[8qWWQ5-swd-WER-DWDS]]<-SUCCESS#[4][MY_SAMPLE_TEST2]
-line[8qWWQ5-swd-WER-DWDS]]<Failed#[17][[14]SERVERERROR(TYPE-241)
```

**Expected output :**

```
MY_SAMPLE_TEST
MY_SAMPLE_TEST2
SERVERERROR
```

My regular expression :  `(?<=#).*`

The above regular expression I can get everything after # , also I tried :

```
rex = (?<=#\[...\[).*(?=])
```

which gives me correct output for the first line i.e : MY_SAMPLE_TEST
but as 2nd line has only one digit i.e 4 so it doesn't matches , similar problem with 3rd line

It is possible to write a single expression which could give the expected out put ? , Any help would be great

Comment: Try `#[^a-zA-Z]*(\w+)` then iterate over values of the first capturing group. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/kSBxMM/1

Comment: There is an extra `[` between `[17]` and `[14]` in the last example string. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Gurman :  No that is not type ,

Comment: @revo Thanks, for quick answer , but what if there is a space in mt matching character i.e MY_SAMPLE_TEST can also be MY SAMPLE TEST

Comment: Then use `#[^a-zA-Z]*([^][()]*)`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/kSBxMM/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may capture these values using

```
#(?:\[+\d+]+)*\[*([^][()]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FunX4u/1)

**Details**

- `#` - a hash sign
- `(?:\[+\d+]+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of:

  - `\[+` - 1+ `[` chars
  - `\d+` -  1+ digits
  - `]+` - 1+ `]` chars
- `\[*` - 0+ `[` chars
- `([^][()]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `(`, `)`, `[` and `]`

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Vo1nQc):

```
import re
strs = ['-line[8qWWQ5-swd-WER-DWDS]]<-SUCCESS#[14][MY_SAMPLE_TEST]', '-line[8qWWQ5-swd-WER-DWDS]]<-SUCCESS#[4][MY_SAMPLE_TEST2]', '-line[8qWWQ5-swd-WER-DWDS]]<Failed#[17][[14]SERVERERROR(TYPE-241)']
rx = re.compile(r'#(?:\[+\d+]+)*\[*([^][()]+)')
for s in strs:
    m = rx.search(s)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Output:

```
MY_SAMPLE_TEST
MY_SAMPLE_TEST2
SERVERERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

Made an assumption that the matched string should be ending just before it finds a closing ] or starting ( characters. Here is the working regex :

```
#(?:\[+\d+\]+)*\[?([^\(\]]+)(?:\(.+\))?\]?
```

It worked on the samples provided without assuming spaces or underscores in the text to be extracted. Here is a demo link : https://regexr.com/47muk